# List row CSS classes no longer supported?

Tags: octobercms

I am trying to follow the October backend user interface style guide at:
https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/list - specifically the `Status column` section.

I need to highlight row cells in green or red.
The guide mention the CSS classes `.negative` and `.positive` and also the `text-danger` and `text-success`, however I can't get them to work.

I am adding the CSS classes in my `columns.yaml` file:

```
    status:
    label: Status
    type: text
    cssClass: 'oc-icon-circle text-danger negative'
```

Here is the generated HTML code when inspected on Chrome browser:

```
<td data-title="Status" class="list-cell-index-4 list-cell-name-status list-cell-type-text oc-icon-circle text-danger negative">
  Blocked
</td>
```

What is wrong of my code above?
Is there any other classes I can use with OctoberCMS to highlight texts in a table row?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you:

In the OctoberCMS doc we can [find](https://octobercms.com/docs/ui/list) some css classes for highlight rows. And we can see an example in the Rainlab.User plugin.

From the controller, only need to add the method `listInjectRowClass`.

```
// This code is part of the \RainLab\User\Controllers\Users
public function listInjectRowClass($record, $definition = null)
{
    if ($record->trashed()) {
        return 'strike';
    }

    if (!$record->is_activated) {
        return 'disabled';
    }
}
```

Source: https://octobercms.com/forum/post/adding-row-class-to-lists-from-behavior